# What heat resistant plastic should I use for a lightbox?

Tags: lighting, plastic

I'm making a lightbox to house a strip light behind a large photographic print. I'd like to use relatively thin (i.e. light) plastic. I looked into using foam PVC, but it's not very heat resistant and I'm worried it would melt.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a lightbox such as are used for viewing film neagtives (or X-Ray films on doctor shows)?  Or just back-lighting behind a displayed print?  I can't really visualize where the plastic is and how it will be exposed to heat.  Also, what are your light sources? Incandesant, flourescent, etc. - and what wattage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for strips but using [these](http://antareslighting.com/ae/odyssey/) may help you with the heat problem.

[image: Antares T4 Odyssey] [image: Antares T4 Odyssey coupled]

They are slim, 7/8" by 1-5/8", not overly expensive and have a lens over them. They can even be mounted on their sides.  These would be cooler to run.  On the plastic, I'm not sure if just want to color the light or turn it into a part of the art piece, like lighting the ends for effects like that.

The nice thing is that there are similar brands so you can get something similar in you area.  Another type of lighting you can use is LED, but it would be 3 or 4 times the price of these.

On the plastic you can always use a piece of opaque white lens from recessed lighting.  You should be able to get them at a lighting store or at a DIY box store, or even an arts and crafts store.

Comment: I have bought a that looks pretty similar to those (they're chainable too). At some point I really want to be able to do this with LED, but the price is prohibitive for the time being. Thanks for the opaque lens tip - that sounds perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Acrylic oughta do, but you should look into using white LED lighting - very low heat.

Comment: thanks, but the white led lighting i've come across is very pricey for the amount of light they cast - not quite at that budget for the moment

Comment: Acrlic has a melting point of 160 °C (320 °F) - is that high enough?